# No operations defined in spec! Java 21 & Spring boot 3.2.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

When I add below dependency for swagger documentation it's not working

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

it should give list of APIs on `swagger-ui/index.html` page but it's giving empty page.

[image: Here is the image]

and below is the controller class

```
import com.vikram.explorespringboot.entity.Person;
import com.vikram.explorespringboot.service.Impl.PersonServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Controller
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    PersonServiceImpl personService;

    @GetMapping("/person/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Person>> getPersonById(@PathVariable int id){
        Optional<Person> person = personService.getPersonById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(person);
    }

    @GetMapping("/persons/{age}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Person>> getPersonByAge(@PathVariable int age){
        List<Person> person = personService.getPersonByAge(age);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(person);
    }

    @GetMapping("/person")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Person>> getPersonList(){
        List<Person> persons = personService.getPersonList();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(persons);
    }

    @PostMapping("/person")
    public ResponseEntity<Person> createPerson(@RequestBody Person person){
        Person newPerson = personService.createPerson(person);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newPerson, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

I just want to enable swagger ui for my api's, i am referring to [this site](https://springdoc.org/#getting-started) after going through many youtube tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the springdoc-openapi java library. I believe the Swagger UI page or rather the OpenAPI UI page would be available at the following style url:

```
http://server:port/context-path/swagger-ui.html
```